# Facebook javascript sdk post on page as page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to post on page as page via FB.api ?
I know how to post as page administrator, but to post as page, we have to use page access token. But I don't know how to call FB.api with page access token.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
                FB.api('/me/accounts', function(apiresponse) {
                    var data = apiresponse['data'];
                    var ids = new Array();
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        ids[i] = data[i].id;
                    }
                    console.log(ids);
                });

            }, { scope: 'manage_pages,publish_pages' });
```